# Abstract algebra book suggestion

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I have been suggested Artin or Herstein's books. What do you think is more rigorous but at the same time clear and good to read?

Comment: For a clear, fun to read text, I highly recommend Pinter's "Book of Abstract Algebra". It is not rigorous, however. But it is absolutely loaded with exercises. I personally love it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lang's Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038795385X) is very nice, and van der Waerden ([vol1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387406247), [vol2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387406255)) is the best I know of, together with [Mac Lane & Birkhoff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821816462). I find the latter significantly harder to follow. There is also [Dummit & Foote](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433349), at a level equivalent to Lang.

I don't own Artin's [Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132413779), but I'd say it's also at the level of Lang, and it has a very good reputation.

**Edit**: the other books I have are of [Emil Artin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Artin). The Artin whose lectures the books by van der Waerden were originally based on (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderne_Algebra) on Wikipedia). [Michael Artin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Artin) is actually his son, and is probably the author you are refering to.

Comment: @user62029 I edited the answer, since I didn't pay much attention: there are two Artin, both well known in algebra :-)

Comment: I think both Lang's and MacLane's books can be terrible for a beginner. Much better, imo, Dummit & Foote. Van der Waerden's already too old, imo again.

Comment: @Timbuc Agreed for MacLane & Birkhoff, which is quite hard, but I don't agree about Lang, I found it very clear, and I actually prefer it other Dummit & Foote. Matter of taste, since they are, I think, almost on the same level.

Comment: I think Lang is even worse than MacClane's for a beginner: it is way too dry, abstract and almost without examples...and it assumes already a lot as *it is a graduate text*. Perhaps you're thinking of Lang's *Undergraduate Algebra* ?

Comment: Lang is terrible for a student. Go with Dummit and Foote.

Comment: @Timbuc No, I had really *Algebra* in mind. Maybe I'm biased since I started with it after I finished my student life. However, having both today (and actually all I mentioned), I still don't agree. Just my humble opinion!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, anyway: Lang's "Algebra" ios for graduate level.

Comment: @Timbuc According to reviews, D&F is for advanced undergraduate or graduate, and I can only confirm they are more or less on the same level, IMO. I guess we could argue endlessly about it. Just an example: both Lang and D&F are used for graduate algebra at Stanford (see [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/10-210A/)) Maybe not the best example, since the prof. finds D&F a better text, and Lang for encyclopedic reference, but anyway...

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the comments.